# Shell script to take input from the user and add it to a specific field in a file

Tags: shell-script

Having text file records.txt with the following info

```
David 5000
Leo 3000
```

How can I add 1000 to salary of David which is 5000 using awk, I want that 1000 to come from the user, meaning to come as a user input. Sed is also fine as long as the input will come from the user

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried something so far?

Comment: `awk '$1 == "David"{$2+=1000}1' records.txt`

Comment: or `read -p "Enter amount: " amount && awk -v a=$amount '/David/ { $2 += a }1'`

Answer (score 0):

Although `awk` can be very powerful, this can also be done in bash as well. Something like the following probably gives you an idea.

```
#!/bin/bin/env bash

while :;
 do
   read -p 'Enter salary: ' amount
   while read -r user salary 
     do printf '%s %d\n' "User salary of $user is now $((salary+amount))"
     done < salary 
 done
```